# How to make an state change when 1 data stored in Store of redux change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a component with state data but I need that one of the states change if data stored in Store of redux change.

I do this way but not work:

```
...in the state I have something like this(obviously more code than this)...
this.state: {
    colapseChange: Store.getState().estados.colapseChange,
}
```

I've checked that it is reachable printing logs and the colapseChange variable is right in the initialState.

Then, I Change the data in the Store and I log it too and when I change the data in the Store I print it.

The problem is that the state is not changing because the render isn't called again. 
And I need when data Store change, render the component again.

The render method is this (I have methods that just returns data, never mind it and just try to understand that is a Flat List):

```
render(){
    console.log('CLICKSTORE',this.state.colapseChange);
    var misCabeceras = this.mostrarPorConsolaClases();
    return(
      <FlatList
        data = {misCabeceras}
        extraData = {this.state.colapseChange}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        renderItem = {({item, index})=>{
          return item.renderThis();
        }}
      />
    );
}
```

So, I need re-render when Store data change but assigning an state to a data Store is not working. Do you have an idea of what am I doing wrong? 
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: can you show where you have created a store

Comment: normally you should connect your Component to the store so it re-renders after each state change, as you did it in your example, your Component won't receive change notification from the store.

Comment: Did you try to just use this.state on extraData prop?

Comment: try to get colapseChange from the props not from local state ?

Comment: It seems that the problem is that I do not connect. I'm going to try it!

Comment: also try to read the data directly from the props: `extraData = {this.props.colapseChange}` because initial state will be executed once.

Comment: I tried extraData = {this.props.colapseChange}, but does not work.
The problem is that I'm not passing nothing to the class. To try reefer to Store data I just make the state assign.

Comment: if your Component is well connected to your app store, it should re-render after each store update, and this.props.colapseChange will be provided again, console it from this.props to be sure that you're well connected and in sync with the store ?

Comment: I don't know how to connect my component to the app store.